# Angular - Check if all Subscriber in a list are finished

Tags: angular, post, foreach, angular5, subscriber

I use an interval to post a variable amount of data in a forEach loop to a backend. What I want to do is: If the first call of the post method is not finished but the interval already wants to call the method a second time, the call should be blocked until the first call it finished.

I try to show this in code

```
setInterval(() => {
  console.log('pendingServiceDataRequests', this.pendingServiceDataRequests);
  if(/* if pendingServiceDataRequests is empty or all subscriber are finished */){
   this.sendData();
  }
}, 5000);


sendData(){
  serviceList = [/* some data */]
  serviceList.forEach((service, index, array) => {
    const currentSub = this.api.post(url, service).subscribe((res: any) => {
            /* delete successful send data */
    }
    this.pendingDataRequests.push(currentSub);
   });
 }
```

I put all Subscriber in a list but I don't know how to check if all requests are finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to call sendData() when all your requests are done and do that in an interval. Try doing something like:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (!this.activeObservable) {
      this.sendData().subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
    }
  }, 5000)
}

sendData() {
  this.activeObservable = true;
  // probably you are calling some service to get a fresh lisyt of data and do post requests over them
  let serviceList = [1,2,3,4,5]; // consider this is your sendData
  // create observables in a loop, don't subscribe them:
  // for you, something like:
  //let allPostData = serviceList.map(service => this.api.post(url, service));
  let dummyPostData = serviceList.map(service => of(service));
  return forkJoin(...dummyPostData).pipe(tap(_ => {this.activeObservable = false;}));
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.timer) {
    clearTimeout(this.timer)
  }
}
```

I am having a flag in the class which tells whether all my requests are done , only themn I call sendData() again, see how I am setting `activeObservable`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggwnxv

To handle errors in individual API calls, have something like:

```
let allPostData = serviceList.map(service => this.api.post(url, service).pipe(
    catchError((e) => { return throwError(e); // handle your error here, can also return of(e) }))
);
```

Comment: Is this possible with Angular 5? But what I still need is to do some operations if one of the request is done or fails

Comment: @WeSt Yes, it would be possible with angular 5, Changes can happen depending on your `rxjs` version. I believe pipeable operators were introduces from rxjs `5.1`, (This should be fine for you). In my given example, imports from `rxjs` can be different than what would be present for you.

Comment: @WeSt Check my edit for handling errors in individual API calls

Answer (score 2):

ConactMap will be correct one for this scenario. Try this:

```
sendData() {
    serviceList = [/* some data */]
    return from(serviceList).pipe(
        concatMap(id => <Observable<Item>> this.api.post(url, service)
    );
}
```

https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293